# Is there any way to create horizontal gradients with CSS borders?

Tags: html, css, border, gradient

I'm trying to create an effect where the border of my DIV object has a horizontal left-to-right gradient fade. The perspective of the gradient must encompass all borders (not just top and bottom)

All the documentation I came across so far describes how to do it vertically

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

All the other answers have just pointed you to a CSS-generator.

While [Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) does a great job at applying vendor-prefixes, the core CSS for it is really simple. Though, I do believe you can get better cross-browser compatibility by using pseudo-elements instead of borders in this scenario. This is how I do it:

Start with a simple div:

```
<div class="top-gradient-border">
    Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Basic CSS:

```
.top-gradient-border {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    /*other irrelevant styling in here*/
}
```

Add the gradiented border (this example shows you how to do it for a `border-top`, change the pseudo-element for other sides):

```
.top-gradient-border::before {
    content: "";
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, black);
    height: 1px; /*for horizontal border; width for vertical*/
    display: block;
}
```

You can learn more about CSS gradients on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/).

Answer (score 1):

Colorzilla allows you to produce gradients using CSS - no graphics files involved. It also works reliably across many browsers.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: +1 because this is an excellent tool. However bear in mind that gradients within a border (as specified in the question) are not as fully cross-browser as regular background gradients.

Answer (score -1):

Photoshop

But check this out, it might just do the trick for you (plus its GUI)

[Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)